# Find section of a string from keyword to keyword

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

So, my code retrieves an HTML file from a URL and saves it as a text document.

```
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.testlink.com", "example.txt")
retrieve = open("example.txt", "r")
```

Then, I want it to pull specific text from lines containing a keyword. The string would look like this:

```
<b class="whb">This is the text I want to retrieve</b> This is additional text that I don't want.
```

Currently, my code prints the ENTIRE line, like so:

```
for line in retrieve.readlines():
    if '<b class="whb">' in line:
        print line
```

How do I specify which part of a line to print? I want what is between b class="whb" and /b.

Thank you.

Comment: Use an html parser, and then pull out all the `b` tags which have class `whb`. You can do this pretty easily with the [HtmlParser class](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/htmlparser.html#module-HTMLParser) in the standard library.

Comment: @ekhumoro Following the code snippets on the docs didnt work. Can't combine str and file objects

Comment: I'd use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: @RyanBroman. You can't pass in a file object - you need to pass in the text (i.e. `parser.feed(retrieve.read().decode('utf-8'))`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I'd use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Here's a little example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = "<b class='whb'>This is the text I want to retrieve</b> This is additional text that I don't want."

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print soup.b.text
```

If you have a `html_doc` is a larger HTML document with several `<b>` tags, you can replace the last line with:

```
print soup.find("b", {"class":"whb"}).text
```

If `html_doc` has multiple `<b class='whb'>` tabs, and you want them all, then use `findAll()`:

```
all_bs = [b.text for b in soup.findAll("b", {"class":"whb"})]
```

BeautifulSoup is an awesome full-featured web-scraper. Please **read the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)** to find what yo need in your specific case.

Comment: I forgot to mention this (sorry!!): I want every instance of <b class="whb">blah blah blah</b>. Your code prints out the first instance. How do I get each instance of this?

Comment: I put my actual code on GitHub here: [link](https://github.com/Ph0enix0/WikiBot/tree/master)

Comment: If you want every instance, you can use BeautifulSoup's `findAll()` method. E.g. `all_bs = [b.text for b in soup.findAll("b", {"class":"whb"})]`. I've just updated my answer to include this.